# Asterisk do not sees queue members

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I have realtimequeue. After restarting asterisk do not sees queue members. When execute on cli this command **“queue pause member SIP/111”** get this error.

```
Unable to pause interface 'SIP/111’
Command ‘queue pause member SIP/111’ failed.
```

But after execute this command **“queue show”** Asterisk sees all queue members.

**Note:** I use realtime config.

```
[settings]
queues => odbc,asteriskdb,queue_table
queue_members => odbc,asteriskdb,queue_member_table
queue_log => odbc,asteriskdb,queue_log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal behavour for realtime queues.

However they still can work and queue will be fetched on first request. It designed so to support thousands of "lazy" queues.

If you want it always be in memory, use realtime config store method.

Comment: No, you use realtime queues. Realtime config is when you put in db config itself using "queues.conf", not "queues". If so, in table should be config file itself line-by-line and it load that only when you do module reload.https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-realtime/ - see static configs section.

Comment: If queue is inactive for some period may be queued state changed from active to inactive ("lazy")?
Or queue fetched once then it will always be active.

Comment: No. "Lazy" mean it NOT load ALL queues. When you ask for queue(exec app_queue) it check in realtime and if found start it. But can be billions of queues in database. Also it read members every time you start queue.

Comment: I have few queues. Is it possible without realtime config load all queues members after restart Asterisk? Or execute queue show command.

Comment: Load - yes. Just create call into each. stats not work for realtime, unless you do it via config load like described above

Comment: Can i write some shell script which runs after restart Asterisk or detect Asterisk loaded and run shell command.

Comment: For most system asterisk started via shell script /usr/sbin/safe_asterisk.sh, just change it.

Comment: Sufficiently just adding to the end of file asterisk -rx 'queue show' ? It will execute after restarting asterisk (after whole opening)?
Or must to wait a few seconds (with shell command sleep xx)